# How to make a 'If Then' Loop in vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop

I am a beginner in vba. I have a situation in which I would like to say if i=9, k=1 and if i=10, k=2 and if i=11, k=3 and it goes on and on

As i increases by one, k should increase by one too. But how do I say if i=1000, k=992. I cant type each one of the statement until i=1000.

So I was just wondering if there are any loops in which I can create here to make it easy. Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: have a look in [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) and come back if you write some code that still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not subtract the constant differences, such as:

```
k = I - 8
```

No `IF` statement required. Does this work?

Answer (score -3):

```
dim k as integer = 0
for i as integer = 9 to 1000 step 1
 k += 1
next
```

Comment: Just a note: VBA doesn't support `+=` to increment values. You'd have to use `k = k + 1`

Comment: Consider providing an explanation for your answer, not just a snippet of code. Also, consider using code that will not raise a compile error.